# Name or class of this "square-wave" shaped microstrip antenna

Tags: antenna, microstrip

I'm interested in researching/designing a microstrip antenna shaped like this one:

[image]

But I'm not sure what phrase to type into google. I can see that this is very similar to an inverted-F antenna, but instead of the quarter wavelength portion being a straight conductor, it's got a square wave shape (I assume this helps fit the antenna into a smaller PCB area...but I'm not 100% sure of that)

Is this a category of antenna that I could google the name of, or is it just one of those trade secret type designs?

Comment: try meander line antenna

Comment: Perfect, that's it. Thank you

Comment: Technically, that is still inverted-F antenna, if you asking for a "class" or a "category". Meandering is just a way to reduce footprint. Here are couple links you might find useful: [Hindawi](https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ijap/2018/5172960.pdf), [CircuitDigest](https://circuitdigest.com/article/how-to-design-a-pcb-antenna-for-24ghz)